# Comparing multiple Object values and manipulating nodes,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, logical-operators, deep-copy

**Expected function:** Create a *new* array that mutates the values in an array of objects. The new values will be objects with a key `value` that was the original value, and another key `duplicate` that is a boolean on if that value is the same as other object values in the same position.

I am attempting to loop the array, then create another array that contains the indexes that *are not* the current index.

Create a deep copy as to not affect the original input, then loop the original array, each loop will capture the keys of the current object.

I am not attempting to change any values deeper than the 1st scope, that's why I am, only mutating the `typeof !== "object"`

I then set the current index, and key to a new object where is `value` will remain the original value, but the `duplicate` is going to be a map of the other indexes, compared to the current index, then reduced to a single boolean using the `.some` method.

After each value in the deep copy has been set, `return` it.

I am currently stuck attempting to create an array containing the indexes that *are not* the current index.

```js
const testState = [
  {
    value1: "1",
    value2: "two",
    value3: 3,
  },
  {
    value1: "one",
    value2: 2,
    value3: "3",
  },
  {
    value1: "1",
    value2: 2,
    value3: "3",
  },
];

const testEquality = (accountArray) => {
  // Deep copy (shallow copies were letting values change)
  const returnedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(accountArray));

  accountArray.forEach((account) => {
    // assign an array that contains ever other index
    const otherIndexes = [];
    for (const key in account) {
      if (typeof key !== "object") {
        returnedArray[i][key] = {
          value: accountArray[i][key],
          // loop every other index, and compare to accountArray[i][key]
          // ex: otherIndexes.map(index => accountArray[index][key] === accountArray[i][key]).some(i => i)
          duplicate: false,
        };
      }
    }
  });

  return returnedArray;
};

testState = testState.map((obj) => testEquality(obj));

console.log(testState);
// output
[
  {
    value1: { value: "1", duplicate: true },
    value2: { value: "two", duplicate: false },
    value3: { value: 3, duplicate: false },
  },
  {
    value1: { value: "one", duplicate: false },
    value2: { value: 2, duplicate: true },
    value3: { value: "3", duplicate: true },
  },
  {
    value1: { value: "1", duplicate: true },
    value2: { value: 2, duplicate: true },
    value3: { value: "3", duplicate: true },
  },
];
```

I am not above a whole refactor and being told this is too inefficient, I have been trying different approaches already, this was just the closest I have gotten.

Comment: These instructions sound like they come from an assignment? If they are, please use blockquote syntax to format them as quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the help yall! I forgot to specify an edge case where the node values *can* be the same, and not considered a duplicate so as they are in a different position in the object.

My answer is not very efficient yet, I will attempt a refactor when I get time. However, it is more important that this function works over its performance.

Here is what I got to work

```js
const testEquality = (accountArray) => {
  // deep copy to prevent original array from being effected
  const returnedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(accountArray));

  accountArray.forEach((account, i) => {

    // array that specifies every other index, besides this one
    const otherIndexes = accountArray
      .map((_, index) => index)
      .filter((index) => i !== index);
    
    for (const key in account) {
    
      // to keep this algorithm from leaving the scope 
      if (typeof key !== "object") {
    
        returnedArray[i][key] = {
          value: accountArray[i][key],
    
          // loop every other index, and compare to accountArray[i][key]
          duplicate: otherIndexes
            .map((index) => accountArray[index][key] === accountArray[i][key])
            .some((i) => i),
        };

      }
    }
  });

  return returnedArray;
};
```

Again! Thank you! I am always thrilled when people answer my questions

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, I believe this is what they are driving towards. First create a mapping of all the values and then later plug those values into your output array. The trouble you were having was due to the additional looping by using `Array.some`. The difference is `O(n)` vs `O(n^2)`.

```js
const testState = [{
    value1: "1",
    value2: "two",
    value3: 3,
  },
  {
    value1: "one",
    value2: 2,
    value3: "3",
  },
  {
    value1: "1",
    value2: 2,
    value3: "3",
  },
];

function testEquality(array) {
  const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
  const map = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const values = Object.values(copy[i]);
    values.forEach(entry => {
      if (!map.has(entry)) {
        map.set(entry, false); // new value, not a duplicate
      } else {
        map.set(entry, true); // we've seen it before mark it as duplicate
      }
    });
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
    const entry = copy[i];
    for (const key in entry) {
      entry[key] = {
        value: array[i][key],
        duplicate: map.get(array[i][key])
      };
    }
  }
  return copy;
}

console.log(testEquality(testState));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const testState = [
  {
    value1: "1",
    value2: "two",
    value3: 3,
  },
  {
    value1: "one",
    value2: 2,
    value3: "3",
  },
  {
    value1: "1",
    value2: 2,
    value3: "3",
  },
];

function transformData(array) {

  const { arr, duplicates } = array.reduce(({ arr, duplicates }, current) => {
    arr.push(
      Object.entries(current).map(([key, value]) => {
        duplicates.push(value);
        return [key, { value }];
      })
    );

    return {
      arr,
      duplicates,
    };
  }, { arr: [], duplicates: [] });

  return arr.reduce((finalArr, cur) => {
    finalArr.push(
      cur.reduce((obj, [nameKey, { value }]) => {
        const duplicatesQty = duplicates.filter(x => x === value).length;
        obj[nameKey] = { value, duplicate: duplicatesQty > 1 ? true : false };
        return obj;
      }, {})
    );

    return finalArr;
  }, []);
}

const test = [
  {
    value1: { value: "1", duplicate: true },
    value2: { value: "two", duplicate: false },
    value3: { value: 3, duplicate: false },
  },
  {
    value1: { value: "one", duplicate: false },
    value2: { value: 2, duplicate: true },
    value3: { value: "3", duplicate: true },
  },
  {
    value1: { value: "1", duplicate: true },
    value2: { value: 2, duplicate: true },
    value3: { value: "3", duplicate: true },
  },
];


console.assert(JSON.stringify(test) === JSON.stringify(transformData(testState)), 'true assert, shouldnt print!');
console.assert(JSON.stringify(test) !== JSON.stringify(transformData(testState)), 'validation confirmation, this should print');
```

there could be a lot of ways to do this... this is how I would do...